Visual Studio Code cannot display pyLDAvis graph with errors
I have run the code below to try to generate an interative graph after fitting my LDA models in VScode:
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
data = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda, corpus_tfidf, dictionary, n_jobs=1)
pyLDAvis.show(data)

However, I got an error afterwards:
TypeError: DataFrame.stack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'future_stack'
It seems that there is something wrong with pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare, which may be caused by the dependencies of pyLDAvis. My pyLDAvis version is 3.4.3, and pandas 1.5.1.
I have tried to downgrade/upgrade both the pyLDAvis and pandas, but the errors continue to show as above. Then I tried to rerun the code in Jupyter client, but surprisingly the result appeared as normal. So in this case I am wondering if there is some way to showcase the result in VS Code. Thank you!
